# re-use '~/.profile` for Fish?

Tags: shell, .profile, fish

(I'm talking about the shell [Fish](http://fishshell.com/), esp. [Fish's Fish](http://ridiculousfish.com/shell/).)

For Bash/ZSH, I had `~/.profile` with some exports, aliases and other stuff.

I don't want to have a separate config for environment variables for Fish, I want to re-use my `~/.profile`. How?

In The FAQ, it is stated that I can at least import those via `/usr/local/share/fish/tools/import_bash_settings.py`, however I don't really like running that for each Fish-instance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `bash` to parse `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, and then start fish.

1. Create `/usr/local/bin/fishlogin` with contents

   ```
    #!/bin/bash -l
    exec -l fish "$@"
   ```
2. Make it executable

   ```
    sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/fishlogin
   ```
3. Check that it works by running `fishlogin` and checking that you end up in a Fish shell. Press Control+D to exit the Fish shell.
4. Add it to `/etc/shells`

   ```
    echo /usr/local/bin/fishlogin | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
   ```
5. Set it as your default shell.

   Under Linux:

   ```
    sudo usermod -s /usr/local/bin/fishlogin $USER
   ```

   Under macOS:

   ```
    chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fishlogin $USER
   ```

Comment: So elegant! Should be the accepted answer IMO

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering, the mac equivalent of `usermod -s /usr/local/bin/fishlogin $USER` is `chsh -s /usr/local/fishlogin $USER`

Comment: If you get `chsh: /usr/local/bin/fishlogin: non-standard shell` need to add it to `/etc/shells`

Comment: To fully imitate launching fish directly, `fish "$@"` should be replaced with `exec -l fish "$@"`. `exec` replaces the bash process with fish, while `-l` causes that `argv[0]` for fish is `-fish`, which signals that this is a login shell.

Comment: Usually no big deal, but this seems to have the drawback that whenever a subshell is implicitly created, an unnecessary bash instance will also always be launched first. (Note: `~/.profile` is only relevant for login shells.) Still upvoted, though, for its good trade-off between simplicity and hackyness. (I'd personally still rather just tweak my shell config scripts a bit, as I've long given up having complicated ones, in favor of custom shell-independent methods.)

Comment: @Sz. Well, nope. Fish does not support subshells in the first place. And even if it did, it would not do so by executing your login shell, so no Bash would be spawned then.

Comment: Note that fish reorders and modifies the entries in `$PATH`, which you might find confusing. See [here](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/927).

Comment: This just broke my Iterm2 on Mac. Followed the exact steps, now I can't even open iTerms.

Comment: If following this answer bricks anyone else's iTerm2, here's how to recover: in iTerm2, "Profile" -> "General", make sure the "Command" is set to "Command" and enter "/bin/sh" as the command (or /bin/bash). Cmd+N open a new shell, then `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish`. Then undo the beginning steps and change "Command" back to `Login Shell`.

Comment: @AsyncMoksha I'm curious to know how it managed to break. Maybe you could try running `fishlogin` from your current shell and see if it prints any interesting error message?

Comment: `~/.profile` gets sourced twice, because `--login` (or `-l`) is used twice, once on `bash` and once on `exec`. Remove one of the `-l` flags.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `exec` builtin does not read `.profile`; all the option does is add a '-' to the start of the first element of argv.

Comment: If anyone's interested, here's an addition that also gets the `.bashrc`'s aliases:
`
#!/bin/bash -i
if [ -d "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" ]; then
    alias > "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"/.bash_aliases
fi
exec -l fish --init-command 'source $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/.bash_aliases' "$@"
`

Comment: small typo -> `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fishlogin $USER` instead of `chsh -s /usr/local/fishlogin $USER`

Comment: @Mr.O thanks, applied

Answer (score 34):

For a much cleaner solution, you can use the [foreign env](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-foreign-env) plugin:

```
fenv source ~/.profile
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. You could elaborate (install omf)

Comment: @JulesRandolph installation of Oh My Fish is not required. The foreign_env fish plugin can be installed alone, it doesn't have dependencies.

Comment: This doesn't handle aliases, which make up 80% of my `.bash_profile`, and is therefore useless to me.

Comment: You can add @jgillich solution in your .config/fish/config.fish file
```
if status is-interactive
    fenv source ~/.profile
end
```

That way .profile will always be synced with fish :)

Answer (score 15):

My current solution (see [here](https://github.com/albertz/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/fish/config.fish) for a maybe more recent version):

```
egrep "^export " ~/.profile | while read e
    set var (echo $e | sed -E "s/^export ([A-Z_]+)=(.*)\$/\1/")
    set value (echo $e | sed -E "s/^export ([A-Z_]+)=(.*)\$/\2/")

    # remove surrounding quotes if existing
    set value (echo $value | sed -E "s/^\"(.*)\"\$/\1/")

    if test $var = "PATH"
        # replace ":" by spaces. this is how PATH looks for Fish
        set value (echo $value | sed -E "s/:/ /g")

        # use eval because we need to expand the value
        eval set -xg $var $value

        continue
    end

    # evaluate variables. we can use eval because we most likely just used "$var"
    set value (eval echo $value)

    set -xg $var $value
end
```

Comment: can you explain what this does?

Comment: @maxpleaner AFAICT it looks through .profile for export statements and executes them as fish sets. It's kinda hacky, but clever.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [bass](https://github.com/edc/bass), a plugin to execute bash commands in fish.

1. [Install bass](https://github.com/edc/bass#installation).

   ```
   $ git clone https://github.com/edc/bass.git
   $ cd bass
   $ make install
   ```
2. And then, just put this in your `config.fish`:

   ```
   bass source ~/.profile
   ```

Comment: If you're going to use this method, make sure it isn't too slow. I personally started to notice that my shell startup delay was annoyingly long, and tracked it down to bass.

Comment: @mk12 probably it isn't bass' fault, it is your `.profile` that has too much going on.

Comment: @rsalmei All I had in there was environment variable and alias definitions, with a few if statements. It causes no noticeable delay in bash. So I think it is bass's fault. On the other hand, I'm much happier with the [fenv plugin](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-foreign-env). It's written in shell rather than Python and seems much faster for me.

Comment: Yeah @mk12, it seems to be nice, but also way more limited, as it only captures environment variables. `bass` on the other hand interprets any bash shell script, and make them run in fish. It certainly will have a bit more overhead, but totally negligible in my experience, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 6):

I tried sourcing .profile on fish startup and it worked like a charm for me.

just do :

```
echo 'source ~/.profile;clear;' >  ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

Restart terminal or iterm2, test an alias from `.profile` to test.

Note : Won't work with more complex .profile files that use syntax not available in fish - credit @erb

Comment: Worked for me too! Running MacOSX.

Comment: Won't work with more complex `.profile` files that use syntax not available in fish.

Comment: @erb I agree with you, I added the caveat in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Install `dash` and add this line to your `config.fish`:

```
env -i HOME=$HOME dash -l -c 'export -p' | sed -e "/PATH/s/'//g;/PATH/s/:/ /g;s/=/ /;s/^export/set -x/" | source
```

Comment: Probably don't even need to install `dash` - just `sh` will do (which is probably dash)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `fish`'s syntax is too different from Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`) syntax. This is the same reason you can't use `.profile` with other non-Bourne-derived shells, such as `csh` and `tcsh`.

Comment: I don't want to fully execute `.profile`. I just want to get all `export`s from there. One easy way would be to `egrep "^export"` which would be good enough already for me. Another, more correct solution would be [this](http://superuser.com/questions/446929/run-any-shell-script-from-fish-and-import-all-exported-env-variables). Also, I e.g. could run this `import_bash_settings.py` script which probably does something similar. So, there are obviously many ways to do this. With my question here, I was wondering how others have solved this.

Answer (score 1):

If your distribution uses [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/), you could set your environment variables in your  [`~/.pam_environment`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAH4ALw.pam_environment) file.

Answer (score 1):

You can start Fish from Bash. If you do that, Fish will inherit all environment variables (`export FOO=bar`) from Bash. At this point, Bash will have already read your `.profile` (or the like).

```
bash-3.2$ export TEST="test"
bash-3.2$ fish
cmey@MBP ~> echo $TEST
test
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding the following to my ~/.bashrc file:

```sh
if [ $SHLVL -lt 2 ]; then 
    fish; 
    exit;
fi
```

This way one does not have to type exit twice when exiting the fish subshell. Bash subshells inside the fish subshell are not affected.